# Example of continuous function with unbounded quadratic variation

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for an example of some $f \in C[0,1]$ with unbounded quadratic variation in the sense of mesh converging. This definition might be most familiar in the brownian motion context. Exact definition given below

Consider a partition $$\Pi_n([0,1])=\{0=t^n_0<\cdots<t^n_{k(n)}=1\}$$  such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{i=1,\cdots,k(n)}|t^n_i-t^n_{i-1}|=0$,

$$V([0,1],\Pi_n)(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{k(n)}(f(t_{i-1})-f(t_i))^2.$$

I'm looking for some $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V([0,1],\Pi_n)(f) = \infty       $$

I was considering $x^{\alpha} \sin(\frac 1x)$ for $\alpha < \frac 12 $ but I'm not sure how to show this formally.

Comment: You say "a partition" but it's really a sequence of partitions.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990232/is-sum-of-differences-bounded-for-c0a-b-functions/2991129#2991129) for the same question and an answer. :-)